# Euler's-method,numerical methods

Tags: matlab

Currently I'm trying to learn about numerical methods, which involves a lot of matlab, there is an example in the book which I would love to use, but it simply wont work, it's looking like this:

```
function [t,y]=euler(inter,y0,n)
t(1)=inter(1); 
y(1)=y0;
h=(inter(2)-inter(1))/n;
for i=1:n
    t(i+1)=t(i)+h;
    y(i+1)=eulerstep(t(i),y(i),h);
end
plot(t,y)

function y=eulerstep(t,y,h)
    y=y+h*ydot(t,y);


function z=ydot(t,y)
    z=t*y+t.^3;
```

And I'm trying to run all of it with only the usage of `euler([0 1],1,10);`
But when I try to run it, I get the warning;
Too many input arguments.

Where did everything go wrong? And help at this point is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`euler` is also a built-in function. Save your m-file with a different name, say `euler11` and change the name of `euler` function to something else, say `euler11`. And then try again by calling it with `euler11([0 1],1,10);`

Making these changes gives me this output:

[image: 1]

The lesson to learn or the good programming practice is to never name your variables/functions with the name of built-in ones.